# Who is heir for Robert and Stannis now?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As we know all three Baratheon brothers died without any heir in *Game of Thrones*. Their father also didn't had any brothers to provide the heirs.

So who is true heir for the kingdom? We know Baratheon are remotely related to Targaryens, however there is also no male heir as of now.

Comment: See also, the same question at the scifi site (but more focused on the books than the TV show): **[Who is the most legitimate heir of the Iron Throne?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60071/who-is-the-most-legitimate-heir-of-the-iron-throne)**

Comment: Tanks for link. In books , I always support the Stannis.

Comment: Also this scifi question: **[Succession of the Iron Throne after GoT Season 5 (spoilers) - who's in line?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93775/succession-of-the-iron-throne-after-got-season-5-spoilers-whos-in-line)**

Comment: ***SPOILERS!***

Answer (score 10):

You forget [Tommen Baratheon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Tommen) who is still alive. We know he is not Robert's biological son but legally and publicly this doesn't change the situation; he is the heir and now head of the house and the throne.

If this question is about the legal claim to the throne: Robert's probably was weak too, he got it by force. Power is power. The same is true for the house before his, the Targaryens. If you win you write history and you will undoubtly find a drop of blood in your ancestry that justifies a claim, as Robert did.

Legally Tommen probably wouldn't have a chance when his true descent would be proven; so some descent of the Targaryens would have a lawful claim.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add i am looking for true claimant. Robert got the throne by right of conquest, not by line of succesion. However Tommen is stoling it, even for right of conquest he needs to declare himself lannister bastard.  And claim the throne.

Comment: Tommen claims to be Robert's descendent, he himself may even believe it still. As long as this isn't disproved he is the legal king. Everyone who tried this is dead (namely Stannis, Ned). How does "right of conquest", i.e. brute force, constitute a different or better claim than "stealing"? The winner is in power afterwards, without any legal claim.

Answer (score 2):

[Gendry](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Gendry), he is the only son (bastard) of Robert Baratheon alive. We don't know where he is but he seems to be the only legislative claim of Baratheon descent. That was the only fear of Joffery which made him kill all the bastards to eliminate any such claim.

Other claims are just going to raise opinions, like Starks deserve it because they were also responsible for winning the war against the Mad King, or the Targaryens because they ruled before, etc etc.

**Note:** *As per the books things are different as there is one more Targaryen claim and Stannis is still alive with his daughter. So as per the books Stannis' claim is more legislative as bastards don't stand against true blood.*

Comment: Unless Gendry gets legitimized he doesn't have claim to the throne. You need a king to legitimize a bastard or have a very large army to do it for you, neither which Gendry has.

Comment: Also, we don't know why Joffrey killed his bastard half-siblings, he might have just been crazy, or maybe he wanted to quell the talk about his legitimacy (their dark hair vs. his blonde).